# How to escape double quotes on schtasks passwords

Tags: passwords, escaping, special-characters, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a scheduled task through **schtasks** comand and I'm struggling on how to escape double quotes (and other possible special characters) for the password on **/RP** parameter.

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "Task name" /tr "powershell D:\path\to\powershell\script\powershellScript.ps1" /ru userName /rp pass"word /rl HIGHEST /f /sc MONTHLY /st 02:00
```

Some examples of what I've tried so far (after a lot of search), nothing working (and all combinations I could think of):

- Enclosing the password with double quotes: **/rp "pass"word"**
- Enclosing the password with single quotes: **/rp 'pass"word'**
- Escaping special characters with ^: **/rp "pass^"word"**
- Escaping special characters with ": **/rp "pass""word"**
- Escaping special characters with : **/rp "pass\"word"**

Every time, the error message I got is always the same (or very similar), suggesting that the double quotes causes the interpretation of the command to break:

> Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'sc' is missing. Type "CREATE /?" for
>   usage.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As the task creation is executed from a PowerShell script, in this particular case, I ended up by searching on the password text and analyzing whether there are double quotes present.

If that's the case, then **schtasks** will prompt to re-enter the password, and that way it doesn't crash.

```
if($password.contains('"')){ #if the password contains double quotes, prompt them, to avoid the task creation to crash
    SCHTASKS /create /tn "Task name" /tr "powershell D:\path\to\powershell\script\powershellScript.ps1" /ru userName /rp * /rl HIGHEST /f /sc MONTHLY /st 02:00
}else{
    SCHTASKS /create /tn "Task name" /tr "powershell D:\path\to\powershell\script\powershellScript.ps1" /ru userName /rp "$password" /rl HIGHEST /f /sc MONTHLY /st 02:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not escaping your backslashes that are part of the command.
I encountered the same problem when trying to schedule syncthing to start and also passing parameters telling it where to look; the troublesome parameters are `-generate=""` and `-home="C:\SyncThing\config"`. For me, the command I needed was:

```
schtasks /create /sc onstart /TN SyncThing /TR "C:\\SyncThing\\syncthing.exe -home=\"C:\\SyncThing\\config\" -generate=\"\""
```

So, put the command along with its parameters inside double quotes, and within that, precede double quotes and backslashes with a backslash. In your case, that would render:

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "Task name" /tr "powershell D:\\path\\to\\powershell\\script\\powershellScript.ps1" /ru userName /rp pass\"word /rl HIGHEST /f /sc MONTHLY /st 02:00
```